# Magento: Add product sorting features to left column

Tags: magento

Is the default left column product/category feature a widget or block... the task I'm trying to perform is adding the Sorting Features to the left column of a custom page. I checked in my theme `catalog.xml` but I see no reference to that column.

the custom page was built without that feature added. im trying to add it back

Answer (score 0):

Look for catalogsearch.leftnav in catalogsearch.xml inside the default theme.
You should copy that layout file to your custom theme and edit it in there.

edit:
Sorry, remembered wrong.
It's been configured in the catalog.xml in default template.
If you lost the files, download your current version and look up the configuration in there.

This should be the configuration in catalog.xml that you're looking for:

```
    <catalog_category_layered translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <!-- <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/su.phtml</template></action> -->
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                    <!--
                        <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>3</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>3</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>9</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>grid</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                    -->
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```